# regex is not working on Kibana

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I'm trying to get an exact match of a field, but unfortunately my regexes aren't working.  I have kibana 4 and elasticsearch 1.4.4 .  I'm using a logstash template in my index, and I have all string fields analyzed and not_analyzed.

Now I'm trying to search inside a field for a string exactly for example, I have these in urlField: `/lang1/page1/`, `/lang2/page1/`, and `/lang3/page1/`, etc.

I tried to play with the regexes to get the above three urls ONLY, but Kibana keeps giving me anything that contains any of the above examples.  For instance, it also returns:

```
`/lang1/page4/other/url/?blahblahblah` and `/hello/this/is/ayman/lang1`
```

Actually, using `not_anaylzed` is working for me, but I have a problem.  For the previous set of urls, the following query works:

```
urlFiled.raw: /lang1/page1/ OR urlFiled.raw:/lang2/page1/  OR urlFiled.raw:/lang3/page1/  # works.
```

Now I'm trying to write a regex to match the above urls in one regex line, such as the following:

```
urlFieldd.raw: / \/(lang1|lang2)\/page1\/ /  #--------> didn't work
urlField.raw: / \/(lang1|lang2\/page1)\/$ /
```

How can I make this regex work?

Comment: what do you mean it's not working? on what level? Kibana doesn't use regex but Apache Lucene Query Syntax!!

Comment: i mean; i want regex to get the exact values.

Comment: use double quotes! urlField:"pageurl"

Comment: i mean; i want regex to get the exact values. `urlFiled.raw: / \/(lang1|lang2)\/page1\/ /` doesn't work for me `urlFiled:  \/(lang1|lang2)\/page1\/ ` returns anything contains lang1 or lang2 or page1

Comment: i tried but as i mentioned it returns anything contains lang1 lang2 or page1 ! @eliasah